# what is the "super" key for linux shortcuts?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I have a regular windows-based keyboard, what button do I press to have it register the "super" key? I don't see anything that says super on it. what do I do?

Answer (score 12):

The super key is the key with the windows logo on it, on regular windows keyboards.

Most of the time it is between <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>.